# Outlook Web Access add-in questions

Tags: outlook-addin

I started developing add-in for OWA for Exchange 2013.
I have a couple of questions related to it.
I would be happy if someone could help me with them.

1. Is it possible to add button(via add-in commands in manifest) to the top pane in OWA?
   http://screencast.com/t/CvOqOsnI
2. Is it possible to get the content of a message? Let's say byte array or base64 string... I've looked through the documentation and have found nothing about it. 
   Office.context.mailbox.item doesn't have method or property to get the content of the message.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As I understand you want to put your extension together with "Move to" and "Categories". If that is what you want, I want to say that it is not possible.
2. Here I have workaround, you can send SOAP request to the Exchange API and get the mail content.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add-in commands are *currently* only [supported](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook) in Outlook 2013 and 2016. They will most likely be available in Outlook Online and Outlook.com at a future date.
2. If [Outlook.context.mailbox.item.Body.getAsync](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Body.html) is not sufficient and you need the full MIME content of the message, use mailbox.makeEWSRequestAsync with a GetItem call that includes the 7C08 extended property:

```html
<!--Call:-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Body" />
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="7C08" PropertyType="Binary" />
        </t:AdditionalProperties>        
      </ItemShape>
      <ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGUzNmEzYTBmLTI1NDItNGE0My1iZDk5LWFkMDgxODI3YWNlOQBGAAAAAACK2VEhi72QSaw+u0XV7xUHBwCMotTyA3QkQ7TPAmcrRt4FAAAALwVMAAAuH/1UA8tzTYD5jbYriaIUAAAJ5576AAA=" />
      </ItemIds>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<!--Response:-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="396" MinorBuildNumber="20" Version="V2015_10_05" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
          <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:Items>
            <t:Message>
              <t:MimeContent CharacterSet="UTF-8">U3ViamVjdDoNClRocmVhZC1JbmRleDogQVFIT3hWSjZLdTJONnltWUxVNlBtQWNpamJYaTdBPT0NCkRhdGU6IFRodSwgMTAgT2N0IDIwMTMgMDA6NDg6NDggKzAwMDANCk1lc3NhZ2UtSUQ6DQoJPGI3MDM3MWNkYjkyZTRhYjc4NzFlM2FjYjgzZjVmMmJlQEJOMVBSMDRNQjM1OC5uYW1wcmQwNC5wcm9kLm91dGxvb2suY29tPg0KQ29udGVudC1MYW5ndWFnZTogZW4tQ0ENClgtTVMtSGFzLUF0dGFjaDoNClgtTVMtVE5FRi1Db3JyZWxhdG9yOg0KQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L3BsYWluOyBjaGFyc2V0PSJ1cy1hc2NpaSINCk1JTUUtVmVyc2lvbjogMS4wDQoNCg==</t:MimeContent>
              <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGUzNmEzYTBmLTI1NDItNGE0My1iZDk5LWFkMDgxODI3YWNlOQBGAAAAAACK2VEhi72QSaw+u0XV7xUHBwCMotTyA3QkQ7TPAmcrRt4FAAAALwVMAAAuH/1UA8tzTYD5jbYriaIUAAAJ5576AAA=" ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAAAuH/1UA8tzTYD5jbYriaIUAAAJ6HVa"/>
              <t:Sensitivity>Normal</t:Sensitivity>
              <t:Body BodyType="Text" IsTruncated="false"/>
              <t:Size>1618</t:Size>
              <t:DateTimeSent>2013-10-10T00:48:48Z</t:DateTimeSent>
              <t:DateTimeCreated>2013-10-10T00:48:47Z</t:DateTimeCreated>
              <t:ResponseObjects>
                <t:ForwardItem/>
              </t:ResponseObjects>
              <t:HasAttachments>false</t:HasAttachments>
              <t:IsAssociated>true</t:IsAssociated>
              <t:IsReadReceiptRequested>false</t:IsReadReceiptRequested>
              <t:IsRead>true</t:IsRead>
            </t:Message>
          </m:Items>
        </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:GetItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: I had to save email as file(.eml or .msg) from OWA, so just body is not good option.

Comment: Currently, I am using it. However message content comes with attachments as well. 
But it is ok.
Thank you Eric.